# How to extract base URL from a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, url

I'm trying to find a relatively easy and reliable method to extract the base URL from a string variable using JavaScript (or jQuery).

For example, given something like:

```
http://www.sitename.com/article/2009/09/14/this-is-an-article/
```

I'd like to get:

```
http://www.sitename.com/
```

Is a regular expression the best bet? If so, what statement could I use to assign the base URL extracted from a given string to a new variable?

I've done some searching on this, but everything I find in the JavaScript world seems to revolve around gathering this information from the actual document URL using *location.host* or similar.

Comment: The now days answer should be [this one below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50449208/696037)

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Edit: Some complain that it doesn't take into account protocol. So I decided to upgrade the code, since it is marked as answer. For those who like one-line-code... well sorry this why we use code minimizers, code should be human readable and this way is better... in my opinion.

```
var pathArray = "https://somedomain.com".split( '/' );
var protocol = pathArray[0];
var host = pathArray[2];
var url = protocol + '//' + host;
```

Or use [Davids solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6167979/213685) from below.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but again, I'm trying to extract the base URL from a string, rather than the actual document URL. I don't think this will help me - though please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: pathArray = String("http://YourHost.com/url/nic/or/not").split( '/' );
host = pathArray[2];

Comment: split works for strings, does not matter where are they coming from

Comment: Got it - thanks Rafal and daddywoodland! I ended up using:
    url = 'http://www.sitename.com/article/2009/09/14/this-is-an-article/';
    pathArray = (url).split('/');
    host = 'http://' + pathArray[2];
I think Rafal's example just omitted the "http://" that is present in all of the strings that I'm processing, in which case the pathArray[2] is the one you need. Without the "http://" prefix, pathArray[0] would be the one. Thanks again.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what happened. Rafal's example was indeed correct, but the "http://" prefix meant that it was interpreted as a link in his comment, so it was truncated from the visible text.

Comment: Yep, It depends if You have http or not. You can always run one more test if first array elm is http or not :)

Comment: Why all the variable declaration? `url = 'sitename.com/article/2009/09/14/this-is-an-article'; newurl = 'http://' + url.split('/')[0];`

Comment: `pathArray = window.location.href.split( '/' );` yes?

Comment: pathArray = window.location.href.split( '/' );
protocol = pathArray[0];
host = pathArray[2];
url = protocol + '://' + host;
`//now url === "http:://stackoverflow.com"`

checkout `::`

Comment: I agree with @TamilVendhan, the code above generates 2 colon's in the protocol section of the URL.  Code should probably read `url = protocol + '//' + host;`

Comment: I updated one line to get rid of query string: 
host = pathArray[2].split('?')[0];

Comment: The fist part of the solution in this answer does not consider credentials in the URL i.e. http://username:password@host.com/some-path. This can be resolved by adding         if(host && host.indexOf("@") !== -1)
          host = host.split("@")[1];

Comment: why not simply location.href.split('/', 3).join('/')?

Comment: here is the one liner using URL API, no need to split and construct the url manually https://stackoverflow.com/a/50449208/6333644

Comment: Please stop. The now days answer is the one provided by [devensvd below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420881/how-to-extract-base-url-from-a-string-in-javascript#answer-50449208)

Answer (score 155):

WebKit-based browsers, Firefox as of version 21 and current versions of Internet Explorer (IE 10 and 11) implement [`location.origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/origin).

`location.origin` includes the **protocol**, the **domain** and optionally the **port** of the URL.

For example, `location.origin` of the URL `http://www.sitename.com/article/2009/09/14/this-is-an-article/` is `http://www.sitename.com`.

To target browsers without support for `location.origin` use the following concise polyfill:

```
if (typeof location.origin === 'undefined')
    location.origin = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
```

Comment: `window.location.hostname` will miss of the port number if given, so use `window.location.host`.

So the complete 'basename' including the trailing slash would be: `window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host + "/";`

Comment: Actually, window.location.hostname is still useful if, as in my case, you need to provide a different port number.

Answer (score 44):

Don't need to use jQuery, just use

```
location.hostname
```

Comment: Thanks - I can't use that with a string, though, can I? My understanding is that will only work with the document URL.

Comment: This will not include protocol and port.

Answer (score 41):

There is no reason to do splits to get the path, hostname, etc from a string that is a link. You just need to use a link

```
//create a new element link with your link
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href="http://www.sitename.com/article/2009/09/14/this-is-an-article/";

//hide it from view when it is added
a.style.display="none";

//add it
document.body.appendChild(a);

//read the links "features"
alert(a.protocol);
alert(a.hostname)
alert(a.pathname)
alert(a.port);
alert(a.hash);

//remove it
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

You can easily do it with jQuery appending the element and reading its attr.

Update: There is now [`new URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) which simplifies it

```js
const myUrl = new URL("https://www.example.com:3000/article/2009/09/14/this-is-an-article/#m123")

const parts = ['protocol', 'hostname', 'pathname', 'port', 'hash'];

parts.forEach(key => console.log(key, myUrl[key]))
```

Comment: Why add 50K of jQuery when you've shown how to do it without jQuery in a few bytes?

Comment: Because the poster says they are using jQuery.

Comment: Ah yes, fair enough. Though when it's as simple as this I see no value in using the extra layer of abstraction that using jQuery would add.

Comment: We're assuming the whole site runs on jqUERY in that case, kquery would indeed simplify things.

Comment: Ewww... this is not the best way to do this... If extracting from window.location.href, use window.location. Otherwise, use a regex.

Comment: I don't think it's required to append the anchor element to the DOM.

Comment: Very nice! This even works when creating a Firefox (53) WebExtension.

Comment: As mentioned above works without adding it to the DOM. Maybe you want to add the missing ; signs .. Pretty smart.Thanks!

Comment: `a.origin` is also usefull pretty often - it's equal to `a.protocol + '//' + a.hostname`

Comment: @Oleg It seems to take port too, eg: `a.protocol + '//' + a.hostname + ':' + a.port`

Answer (score 37):

Well, [URL API object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) avoids splitting and constructing the url's manually.

```
 let url = new URL('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420881');
 alert(url.origin);
```

Answer (score 21):

```
var host = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/';
```

Comment: This should be considered the correct answer - it keeps the protocol

Answer (score 16):

```
String.prototype.url = function() {
  const a = $('<a />').attr('href', this)[0];
  // or if you are not using jQuery 
  // const a = document.createElement('a'); a.setAttribute('href', this);
  let origin = a.protocol + '//' + a.hostname;
  if (a.port.length > 0) {
    origin = `${origin}:${a.port}`;
  }
  const {host, hostname, pathname, port, protocol, search, hash} = a;
  return {origin, host, hostname, pathname, port, protocol, search, hash};

}
```

Then :

```
'http://mysite:5050/pke45#23'.url()
 //OUTPUT : {host: "mysite:5050", hostname: "mysite", pathname: "/pke45", port: "5050", protocol: "http:",hash:"#23",origin:"http://mysite:5050"}
```

For your request, you need :

```
 'http://mysite:5050/pke45#23'.url().origin
```

## Review 07-2017 : It can be also more elegant & has more features

```
const parseUrl = (string, prop) =>  {
  const a = document.createElement('a'); 
  a.setAttribute('href', string);
  const {host, hostname, pathname, port, protocol, search, hash} = a;
  const origin = `${protocol}//${hostname}${port.length ? `:${port}`:''}`;
  return prop ? eval(prop) : {origin, host, hostname, pathname, port, protocol, search, hash}
}
```

Then

```
parseUrl('http://mysite:5050/pke45#23')
// {origin: "http://mysite:5050", host: "mysite:5050", hostname: "mysite", pathname: "/pke45", port: "5050"…}


parseUrl('http://mysite:5050/pke45#23', 'origin')
// "http://mysite:5050"
```

Cool!

Answer (score 12):

If you're using jQuery, this is a kinda cool way to manipulate elements in javascript without adding them to the DOM:

```
var myAnchor = $("<a />");

//set href    
myAnchor.attr('href', 'http://example.com/path/to/myfile')

//your link's features
var hostname = myAnchor.attr('hostname'); // http://example.com
var pathname = myAnchor.attr('pathname'); // /path/to/my/file
//...etc
```

Comment: I think it should be `myAnchor.prop('hostname')`. I'm guessing that jQuery has changed in the last 5 years... Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 10):

A lightway but complete approach to getting basic values from a string representation of an URL is Douglas Crockford's regexp rule:

```
var yourUrl = "http://www.sitename.com/article/2009/09/14/this-is-an-article/";
var parse_url = /^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))?(?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/;
var parts = parse_url.exec( yourUrl );
var result = parts[1]+':'+parts[2]+parts[3]+'/' ;
```

If you are looking for a more powerful URL manipulation toolkit try [URI.js](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js) It supports getters, setter, url normalization etc. all with a nice chainable api.

If you are looking for a jQuery Plugin, then [jquery.url.js](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) should help you

A simpler way to do it is by using an anchor element, as @epascarello suggested. This has the disadvantage that you have to create a DOM Element. However this can be cached in a closure and reused for multiple urls:

```
var parseUrl = (function () {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  return function (url) {
    a.href = url;
    return {
      host: a.host,
      hostname: a.hostname,
      pathname: a.pathname,
      port: a.port,
      protocol: a.protocol,
      search: a.search,
      hash: a.hash
    };
  }
})();
```

Use it like so:

```
paserUrl('http://google.com');
```

Answer (score 9):

A good way is to use JavaScript native api `URL` object. This provides many usefull url parts.

For example:

```
const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420881/how-to-extract-base-url-from-a-string-in-javascript'

const urlObject = new URL(url);

console.log(urlObject);


// RESULT: 
//________________________________
hash: "",
host: "stackoverflow.com",
hostname: "stackoverflow.com",
href: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420881/how-to-extract-base-url-from-a-string-in-javascript",
origin: "https://stackoverflow.com",
password: "",
pathname: "/questions/1420881/how-to-extract-base-url-from-a-string-in-javaript",
port: "",
protocol: "https:",
search: "",
searchParams: [object URLSearchParams]
... + some other methods
```

As you can see here you can just access whatever you need.

For example: `console.log(urlObject.host); // "stackoverflow.com"`

doc for [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

Answer (score 8):

If you are extracting information from window.location.href (the address bar), then use this code to get `http://www.sitename.com/`:

```
var loc = location;
var url = loc.protocol + "//" + loc.host + "/";
```

If you have a string, `str`, that is an arbitrary URL (not window.location.href), then use regular expressions:

```
var url = str.match(/^(([a-z]+:)?(\/\/)?[^\/]+\/).*$/)[1];
```

I, like everyone in the Universe, hate reading regular expressions, so I'll break it down in English:

- Find zero or more alpha characters followed by a colon (the protocol, which can be omitted)
- Followed by // (can also be omitted)
- Followed by any characters except / (the hostname and port)
- Followed by /
- Followed by whatever (the path, less the beginning /).

No need to create DOM elements or do anything crazy.

Answer (score 7):

You can use below codes for get different parameters of Current URL

```
alert("document.URL : "+document.URL);
alert("document.location.href : "+document.location.href);
alert("document.location.origin : "+document.location.origin);
alert("document.location.hostname : "+document.location.hostname);
alert("document.location.host : "+document.location.host);
alert("document.location.pathname : "+document.location.pathname);
```

Answer (score 7):

I use a simple regex that extracts the host form the url:

```
function get_host(url){
    return url.replace(/^((\w+:)?\/\/[^\/]+\/?).*$/,'$1');
}
```

and use it like this

```
var url = 'http://www.sitename.com/article/2009/09/14/this-is-an-article/'
var host = get_host(url);
```

Note, if the `url` does not end with a `/` the `host` will not end in a `/`.

Here are some tests:

```
describe('get_host', function(){
    it('should return the host', function(){
        var url = 'http://www.sitename.com/article/2009/09/14/this-is-an-article/';
        assert.equal(get_host(url),'http://www.sitename.com/');
    });
    it('should not have a / if the url has no /', function(){
        var url = 'http://www.sitename.com';
        assert.equal(get_host(url),'http://www.sitename.com');
    });
    it('should deal with https', function(){
        var url = 'https://www.sitename.com/article/2009/09/14/this-is-an-article/';
        assert.equal(get_host(url),'https://www.sitename.com/');
    });
    it('should deal with no protocol urls', function(){
        var url = '//www.sitename.com/article/2009/09/14/this-is-an-article/';
        assert.equal(get_host(url),'//www.sitename.com/');
    });
    it('should deal with ports', function(){
        var url = 'http://www.sitename.com:8080/article/2009/09/14/this-is-an-article/';
        assert.equal(get_host(url),'http://www.sitename.com:8080/');
    });
    it('should deal with localhost', function(){
        var url = 'http://localhost/article/2009/09/14/this-is-an-article/';
        assert.equal(get_host(url),'http://localhost/');
    });
    it('should deal with numeric ip', function(){
        var url = 'http://192.168.18.1/article/2009/09/14/this-is-an-article/';
        assert.equal(get_host(url),'http://192.168.18.1/');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having to account for window.location.protocol and window.location.origin, and possibly missing a specified port number, etc., just grab everything up to the 3rd "/":

```
// get nth occurrence of a character c in the calling string
String.prototype.nthIndex = function (n, c) {
    var index = -1;
    while (n-- > 0) {
        index++;
        if (this.substring(index) == "") return -1; // don't run off the end
        index += this.substring(index).indexOf(c);
    }
    return index;
}

// get the base URL of the current page by taking everything up to the third "/" in the URL
function getBaseURL() {
    return document.URL.substring(0, document.URL.nthIndex(3,"/") + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function getBaseURL() {
    var url = location.href;  // entire url including querystring - also: window.location.href;
    var baseURL = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('/', 14));


    if (baseURL.indexOf('http://localhost') != -1) {
        // Base Url for localhost
        var url = location.href;  // window.location.href;
        var pathname = location.pathname;  // window.location.pathname;
        var index1 = url.indexOf(pathname);
        var index2 = url.indexOf("/", index1 + 1);
        var baseLocalUrl = url.substr(0, index2);

        return baseLocalUrl + "/";
    }
    else {
        // Root Url for domain name
        return baseURL + "/";
    }

}
```

You then can use it like this...

```
var str = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knopf?q=1&t=2';
var url = str.toUrl();
```

The value of url will be...

```
{
"original":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knopf?q=1&t=2",<br/>"protocol":"http:",
"domain":"wikipedia.org",<br/>"host":"en.wikipedia.org",<br/>"relativePath":"wiki"
}
```

The "var url" also contains two methods.

```
var paramQ = url.getParameter('q');
```

In this case the value of paramQ will be 1.

```
var allParameters = url.getParameters();
```

The value of allParameters will be the parameter names only.

```
["q","t"]
```

Tested on IE,chrome and firefox.

Comment: I think I´m missing something... Where is toUrl coming from?

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
location.href.split(location.pathname)[0];
```

Comment: fails in the case where `location.pathname = '/'`

Answer (score 2):

Implementation:

```
const getOriginByUrl = url => url.split('/').slice(0, 3).join('/');
```

Test:

```
getOriginByUrl('http://www.sitename.com:3030/article/2009/09/14/this-is-an-article?lala=kuku');
```

Result:

```
'http://www.sitename.com:3030'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a regex :

```
/(http:\/\/)?(www)[^\/]+\//i
```

does it fit ?

Comment: Hmm, from my limited regex skills, it looks like that's at least close. I'll add some more information to the question to see if I can help narrow down the best regex.

Comment: I ended up using .split('/') on the string just because it was an easier solution for me. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: https URLs? Host names not starting with www? Why capture the www anyway?

Comment: I don't know, the OP asked how to catch a url, and in his example there was http & www.

Answer (score 1):

To get the origin of any url, including paths within a website (`/my/path`) or schemaless (`//example.com/my/path`), or full (`http://example.com/my/path`) I put together a quick function.

In the snippet below, all three calls should log `https://stacksnippets.net`.

```js
function getOrigin(url)
{
  if(/^\/\//.test(url))
  { // no scheme, use current scheme, extract domain
    url = window.location.protocol + url;
  }
  else if(/^\//.test(url))
  { // just path, use whole origin
    url = window.location.origin + url;
  }
  return url.match(/^([^/]+\/\/[^/]+)/)[0];
}

console.log(getOrigin('https://stacksnippets.net/my/path'));
console.log(getOrigin('//stacksnippets.net/my/path'));
console.log(getOrigin('/my/path'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This, works for me:

```js
var getBaseUrl = function (url) {
  if (url) {
    var parts = url.split('://');
    
    if (parts.length > 1) {
      return parts[0] + '://' + parts[1].split('/')[0] + '/';
    } else {
      return parts[0].split('/')[0] + '/';
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tilllastbackslashregex = new RegExp(/^.*\//);
baseUrl = tilllastbackslashregex.exec(window.location.href);
```

window.location.href   gives the current url address from browser address bar

it can be any thing like  https://stackoverflow.com/abc/xyz or https://www.google.com/search?q=abc   tilllastbackslashregex.exec() run regex and retun the matched string till last backslash ie https://stackoverflow.com/abc/ or https://www.google.com/ respectively

Comment: Please add brief description.

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.