# How to get previous page URL using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to get previous page URL using jQuery?

I am using the following code to get the current page location

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
});
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Easy as pie.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var referrer =  document.referrer;
});
```

It is not always available though.

Comment: Note to Geetha: document.referrer is plain old JavaScript, so that might the reason that you can't find it browser the jQuery docs.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. How can I write the output in a input value?

Comment: just bellow the var you could make it write this to a text field for example... document.getElementByID("myField").value=referrer; You could write it to a div as well. Many different ways

Comment: To put it in an input value using jQuery: $('#input-id').val(document.referrer);

Comment: I needed to implement my GoBack() js function then i tried this
function GoBack()
{
history.go(-1)
}
but this has an issue when you deal with confirmation messages 
but document.location.href = document.referrer;
worked as a pretty .... Many thanks Marcos : )))

Comment: This is ok and working fine but can we get only domain from referrer? @MarcosPlacona

Comment: Hey @GobindGupta have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317017/javascript-get-domain-only-from-document-referrer

Comment: @MarcosPlacona, Thanks for efforts, i have also got the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Do you mean something like `history.go(-1);`? It will go back to the previous page.

[window.history on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using PHP, you can check previous url using php script rather than javascript.
Here is the code:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Hope it helps even out of relevance :)

Comment: I'm not sure what part of 'using jQuery' you missed with this.

Comment: It's still helpful.

Answer (score 5):

```
var from = document.referrer;
console.log(from);
```

`document.referrer` won't be always available.

Answer (score 3):

We have document.referrer for this, but it is not on which we can relay. This could be saved, could be not

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var referrer =  document.referrer;
});
```

The better approach is to add a cookie to store the previous-url in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

simple & sweet

```
window.location = document.referrer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use one of below this

```
history.back();     // equivalent to clicking back button
history.go(-1);     // equivalent to history.back();
```

I am using as below for back button

```
<a class="btn btn-info float-right" onclick="history.back();" >Back</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
               var referrer =  document.referrer;

               if(referrer.equals("Setting.jsp")){                     
                   function goBack() {  
                        window.history.go();                            
                    }
               }  
                   if(referrer.equals("http://localhost:8080/Ads/Terms.jsp")){                     
                        window.history.forward();
                        function noBack() {
                        window.history.forward(); 
                    }
                   }
    });
```

> using this you can avoid load previous page load

Answer (score -3):

document.referrer is not working always.

You can use:

```
window.location.origin
```

Comment: `window.location.origin` provides the root of the website NOT the referrer. e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420881/javascript-jquery-method-to-find-base-url-from-a-string` (which incidentally is my reference) becomes `http://stackoverflow.com`