# problem with same search tab in multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search-engine, dhtml

I have some ten html pages each page has same search tab, when i click search button from any of the page it navigates to index page with search text passed through query string and displays output on the index page . How can i write click on the index page with search parameters entered from index page search tab and display the results on the index page.
I used the following logic:
example1.html
......

```
$("#SearchButton").click(function() {
    var address = ($("#s1").val());
    var keyword2 = ($("#s2").val());
    var radius2 = ($("#s3").val());
    $.cookie("spaddress", address);
    $.cookie("spkeyword", keyword2);
    $.cookie("spradius", radius2);
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:4745/blsk22-9-2010/seek.html?page1=1";
    });
```

......
..
index.html
.....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var page1 = Request.QueryString("page1");
    alert(page1);
    if (page1 == 1) {

            map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('SearchMap'));
                var keyword1 =  $.cookie('spkeyword');
                var radius = $.cookie('spradius');
                var address1 = $.cookie('spaddress'); 
....
....
}
else
{
$("#SearchButton").click(function() {

                    var keyword1 = ($("#text1").val());
                    var radius = ($("#radiusSelect").val());
                    var address1 = ($("#addressLocation").val());
....
.....
.....
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I can't understand what you want to know.

Comment: If their are two html pages example1.html and example2.html .when i navigate to example2.html from example1.html how will check in example2.html that i have navigated from example1.html itself

Answer (score 0):

Use [document.referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415633/how-to-get-previous-page-url-using-jquery) to find out what page was used to get to the current page, and [.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to convert input values into query string parameters.