# Fetching the url of previous page in html?

Tags: html, referrer

I have an HTML page which contains an href tag.
On clicking href link, I get a new page opened.
What I want to do is fetch the url of the previous page,
on which I had the href link, in my current page.

Please help.
Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get previous page url using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415633/how-to-get-previous-page-url-using-jquery)

Comment: Are you using any server side languages? If yes, which one?

Comment: Note, the duplicate says it's jQuery however it's pure JavaScript. It can't be found with pure HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How to get previous page url using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415633/how-to-get-previous-page-url-using-jquery)

With jQuery 'wrapper' of sorts:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var referrer =  document.referrer;
});
```

Or you can just integrate `var referrer =  document.referrer;` into your plain javascript.

Comment: Just use `var referrer =  document.referrer;`

Answer (score 3):

try getting the referrer URL or you can also pass the previous url in the href link:

for passing the the prev url to the href link you can you can use javascript:

```
<a href="newurl.html" id="link1">kdjfdkjfkdjf</a>

<script>
   window.onload = function(){
     var a = document.getElementById("link1");
     a.href = a.href + "?prevurl=" + escape(document.location.href);
   }
</script>
```