# javascript - get domain ONLY from document.referrer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get ONLY the domain from the referrer urls. The referrer urls I mostly get are `http://www.davidj.com/pages/flyer.asp` & `http://www.ronniej.com/linkdes.com/?adv=267&loc=897`

Whenver I get referrer urls like the above, I just want to get the domain example: http://www.davidj.com

I have tried using the .split method but i am having trouble using it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var url = "http://www.ronniej.com/linkdes.com/?adv=267&loc=897"
var referrer =  url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hyjcD/

```
if (document.referrer) {
   url = document.referrer; 
   ref = url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];
}
```

Comment: @Reminson  thanks for this ..it works but I have a problem.. I have placed the code on my domain using a .js file and basically it is being loaded on all of the pages. The only problem is this. whenever I access a page directly (without having a referrer url) I am getting the following error saying:  url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1]; **is null**

Comment: I am using this: 

var url = unescape(document.referrer);
var ref = url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];

Comment: that's because `document.referrer` is `undefined` and there is no url to match, you should check `if (document.referrer)' is not "undefined" and then execute this code.

Comment: just this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52850936/1407491

Answer (score 11):

Try the JS native URL interface for handling URL strings:

```js
let domain = (new URL(document.referrer)).hostname;

console.log(domain);
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: Use .host to have the port included

Answer (score 10):

you can use internally write the url to an anchor element and from that one get the smaller parts

```
var anchor = document.createElement("a");
anchor.href = "http://www.davidj.com/pages/flyer.asp";

console.log(anchor.protocol + "//" + anchor.host); // "http://www.davidj.com"
```

it is far easier then as you do not have to take care about splitting or something like that... it is quite logical... the native anchor has the same properties like `window.location` at least regarding the URL

EDIT: IE 6-9 adds the default port to anchor.host // "http://www.davidj.com:80

Comment: IE does appear to add the port to `anchor.host`, but not to `location.host`. You can use `anchor.hostname` and `location.hostname` instead, if you don't need the port.

Answer (score 5):

Chain split, slice and join:

```
document.referrer.split("/").slice(0,3).join("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex:

```
var matchHost = /^https?:\/\/.*\//;

var match = matchHost.exec('http://www.davidj.com/pages/flyer.asp');
if(match) {
    var host = match[0];
    console.log(host);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.referrer.split('/')[2] == "domain") {
    //................
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The only answer to get protocol + domain from referrer string is:

```
document.referrer.split("/").slice(0,3).join("/").split("?").slice(0,1).join("?")
```

The second split is needed to remove query-string if exists: **http://www.example.com?s=search**

it will work for:

1. http://....
2. https://....
3. http://www.example.com
4. http://www.example.com/
5. http://www.example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc....
6. http://www.example.com?s=search&t=time
7. http://www.example.com/?s=search&t=time

Comment: Doesn't work with `file:///home/user/desktop/page.html`

Comment: @user5994461  - I'm not sure what is "domain" when talking about local url, there is no domain for such urls