# Getting the URL which redirected to this page

Tags: javascript, referrer

In this code:

```
if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://www.megaoferta.bg/mobile";
}
```

How can I identify the URL from whom the page is opened with JavaScript?

For example, if people get to my page from a Google search, how can I obtain the page "google.com" using JavaScript?

Comment: as a side note, never use `window.location` ... use `window.location.href`. it has nothing to do with answering the question, just would be remiss if i didnt mention it.3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415633/how-to-get-previous-page-url-using-jquery

Answer (score 6):

You can use the document referrer:

```
var x = document.referrer;
```

Comment: This is taking the whole URL adress, how can i get only the domain ? for example: google.com without the `http://` and `www`

Comment: This won't work if the referrer is using SSL. Google has turned on SSL by default.