# How to get the url first entered in the browser

Tags: jquery, url, cookies

I entered www.abc.com/123 in the browser
THe site detects user is not login so it automatically redirects it to login url www.abc.com/login.

On the login page, I have a script running (Jquery)

I want to get the url of the referral from the login page. Meaning I want to get the url of www.abc.com/123.

How I can achieve this from a jquery code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get previous page url using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415633/how-to-get-previous-page-url-using-jquery)

Comment: I checked and that does not solve it, I was not able to get the first url entered before redirecting the page to login page

Comment: var x = document.referrer;
alert(x)
I have tried this but there is no result, I run it from www.abc.com/login after it was redirected automatically from  www.abc.com/123

Comment: How do you detect that a user is not logged in? I am thinking that's the point you need to capture the URL and either send it as a URL parameter or store it in local storage or as a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to find the last page a user was at is to send it through a `$_GET`

something like this...

```
$last_page = '?last=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$last_redirect = 'Location: http://www.example.com/' . $last_page;
header($last_redirect);
```

and then on the login page

```
$login_last_redirect = $_GET['last'];
header($login_last_redirect);
```

I believe that's how facebook does it

Comment: Is there a Jquery version of this? I can only run jquery from login page

Comment: i'm not sure. I don't mess with jquery too much. Does the redirect process take place within the jquery process? Why can't you define the variable before running jquery script? Unless i'm missing something obvious.