# How to get the domain name from anchor href attribute?

Tags: jquery

I have a url like e.g.:

```
http://www.intereconomia.com/noticias-gaceta/politica/grinan-los-casos-corrupcion-pueden-influir-20120226
```

I want only in my link text:

```
http://www.intereconomia.com
```

but the href go to:

```
http://www.intereconomia.com/noticias-gaceta/politica/grinan-los-casos-corrupcion-pueden-influir-20120226
```

What regex jquery can do this functionality?

Comment: Possible dupe?  See this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420881/javascript-jquery-method-to-find-base-url-from-a-string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a regex you can try this which is clean and simple.

```
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).text(this.protocol + "//" + (this.hostname || this.pathname));
});​
```

Note: If you want to set it only for set of anchors, then change the selector accordingly but the logic inside remains the same.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/8G7JM/3/

Comment: @hyperrjas - Check my edited answer, now added the `protocol` also and support for `pathname` in case `hostname` is not available in some browsers.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're asking for a simple anchor tag (if you need some specific jQuery/JavaScript action, please elaborate):

```
<a href="http://www.intereconomia.com/noticias-gaceta/politica/grinan-los-casos-corrupcion-pueden-influir-20120226">
    http://www.intereconomia.com
</a>
```

Comment: I generate a link with ruby code `<%= link_to @post.url, @post.url, :target => "_blank", :class => "from_url" %>`

Answer (score 1):

You can add text to display for the link:
    `<a href="http://www.intereconomia.com/noticias-gaceta/politica/grinan-los-casos-corrupcion-pueden-influir-20120226">Click Here</a>`

However, I would not suggest making the text `http://www.intereconomia.com` as that is usually seen as a bad practice to link to an inner-page when the user is expecting to go to `http://www.intereconomia.com`

Instead use a descriptive link to mask the url.

Answer (score 1):

```
//wait for `document.ready` to fire so the DOM elements are available to modify
$(function () {

    //iterate through all the `<a>` elements in the DOM
    $.each($('a'), function () {

        //get the text of the current `<a>` element and then use RegExp to get everything after the `.com/`
        var url   = $(this).text(),
            other = url.replace(/^(http|https):\/\/(.){0,99}(\.com|\.net|\.org)/, '');

        //now change the text of this `<a>` element to not display anything after the `.com/`
        $(this).text(url.replace(other, ''));
    });
});​
```

​
There is probably a more elegant solution but this should do the trick.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/DssEs/2/

Comment: Can you delete the end slash **/** `http://www.intereconomia.com` without final slash /. Thank you

Comment: @hyperrjas sure, just had to remove the `\/` from `(.com\/)`: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/DssEs/2/

Comment: Thank Jasper, but only works with .com domains. Its possible that works fine with ith any domain?. Thank you

Comment: @hyperrjas I added `.net`/`.org`, you can add more by changing this piece of RegExp: `(\.com|\.net|\.org)`, just add `|\.blah` to include `.blah` domains.