# Get base url of link with no http/https with jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that many people have already posted this, including [hyperrjas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488713/how-to-get-the-domain-name-from-anchor-href-attribute),
but they always are looking to transform `http://example.com/fawoefj/faeewjfp` into a domain like this: `http://example.com`.

However, I would like it to transform into a domain like: `example.com`

Comment: The link you posted gives you exactly the answer.

Comment: @Steve I tried it and it gave `http://example.com`, not `example.com`

Comment: You don't have to use the answer exactly as written, look closer and see what is being returned. (hint: `this.protocol` returns `http:`)

Comment: @Steve Aww... I see. Change it to `...text(this.host)`. Thanks for the hint, KhaledMohamedP also pushed me in the right direction. If you make an answer, I'll accept it since you help first, but until then...

Comment: @ChrisHappy hey I posted an answer since you said it was helpful. I have also added magic regex which I think* it will work for all urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following can help you get the hostname

`window.location.host`

also if you are a regex fan like I am, this will work:

```
urlString = "http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40337155/"

urlString.replace(/^(http|https):\/\//, '').replace(/\/.+/, '');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not accepting it because I was trying to get the host name of a link, not the current window. (I don't have much experience with regex.

Comment: @ChrisHappy it's ok. The regex posted is not fully tested anyway. I would love to see where it actually fails though . Hope you find the right answer :)

Comment: I got it, after your and Steve's hint, my final code was `$("a").each(function(){ $(this).text(this.host); });`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This removes the full path if there is one, but leaves the trailing slash if there isn't one ... `http://example.com/` becomes `example.com/` ... you need this to remove the lone single slash `.replace(/\/.*/, '');`