# How to get the text after the # symbol in a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple link with a hashtag in it. ie:

```
<a class="page_navigation" href="#something">click</a>
```

On clicking this, I would like to just end up with the 'something' part (minus the hash) in a var.

So far I have

```
$('.page_navigation').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Obviously I just end up with '#something' in my href var with the above code, and I understand I could do some kind of regex (not sure how yet) to strip the #, but I wonder if there is an easier way to access this part of the href I'm unaware of, without having to go through some find and replace code.

Any ideas?

Note: I also know I could store the 'something' in a data tag, but I'm trying to keep this code as DRY as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know it has a `#` in it, you can use this:

```
$('.page_navigation').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.href.replace(/^.*#/, "");
});
```

If you don't know whether it has one it it or not, you can use this:

```
$('.page_navigation').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var hash = "";
    if (this.href.indexOf("#") {
        hash = this.href.replace(/^.*#/, "");
    }
});
```

In [HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement), you could use:

```
this.hash
```

but that is only for the latest browsers.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it'd be a little bit nicer if you use `location.hash` in place of href.. .just incase somehow they have a `#` in the middle of the url somehow?

Comment: @mazlix - `location.hash` only works on the page URL.  This question is about an URL in a link.

Comment: Doesn't your first one work even if there might not be a hash there? If there isn't the pattern won't match so nothing will be replaced. The second way won't work if the hash is the first character because `.indexOf()` would return 0.

Comment: @nnnnnn - I was assuming the desired result if no hash is present is an empty string and the first one will return the entire URL in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
var theHash = $(this).prop("hash").substr(1);
```

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420881/javascript-jquery-method-to-find-base-url-from-a-string/1421037#1421037) to another question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions for this. You can simply do

```
var fragment;

if (window.location.hash) {
    fragment = window.location.hash;
}
```

Note that this will pick up the # symbol as well. So,

`fragment = "#something"`

If you don't want the # symbol, use `substring` like this:

```
fragment = window.location.hash.substring(1)
```

If you want to pick out the hash fragment from an anchor tag, you can do this:

```
var link = $('#yourAnchor').attr('href');
var fragment;
if (link.indexOf("#") !== -1) {
    fragment = link.substr(link.indexOf("#") + 1);
}
```

Comment: -1 The OP is asking about a link in an `<a>` tag, not the location of the current page.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. Editing answer

Answer (score 0):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/UR3XN/

**code**

```
$('.page_navigation').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var equalPosition = href.indexOf('#'); //Get the position of '#'
    var withouthash = href.substring(equalPosition + 1); 
    alert(withouthash);
});​
```