# JavaScript: How to get an absolute Base-URL?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, templates

I would like to avoid JavaScript in my HTML/PHP-Templates. Everything is working fine as long as I don't need a base/root-URL in my external, included JS-File.

**Problem**:
Does anybody know a solution to put the JS logic (code below) into an external JS file? The main problem: how to figure out the _BASE_URL_? Unfortunately its not a form where you can get the URL by the action-attribute. I dont want to compile JS/PHP-mixed files, it has to be pure JS.

**Idea** (too dirty): A hidden input in the top of the body-tag with id="root_url" or a variable in the main JS file: root_url = "http://localhost/projects/project/version/". This is prone to failure, because no file could work stand-alone.

Maybe there's a good htaccess/mod_rewrite solution?

**Notice**: I dont want to get the hostname or the "real" root dir, because it has to work in subfolders as well!

**Code**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// document ready
$(function() {
    // function: load items
    function load_items() {
        $("#items").load("<?php echo _BASE_URL_?>/items.php");
    }

    // load items!
    load_items();
});
</script>

<!-- target div --> 
<div id="items">loading</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can i see your html structure

```
function getBaseURL () {
   return location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + (location.port && ":" + location.port) + "/";
}
```

if you need a path also use this

```
path = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
console.log(path);
```

Comment: Your function would work better with something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11775016/1431728.

Answer (score 0):

can we use like this

```
function getBaseURL () {
    return location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + location.pathname;


}
```