# How to "safely" load a page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I want to write a small function that takes a URL as a parameter, but before loading that URL, it checks if it is already on that page. If so, it returns `false` and nothing happens; otherwise, it loads the specified URL. I tried something like this:

```
function load(url) {
    if(window.location.href === url) {
        return false;
    } else {
        window.location.href = url;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, if my current page is http://www.example.org/index.html, then, while calling `load('http://www.example.org/index.html')` does nothing, when I call `load('index.html')`, it reloads the page. How can I add the extra functionality to catch relative addresses as well as absolute ones?

EDIT: I want to make this dynamic, so that I can use this on any page, without knowing the base of its URL.

Comment: you can get a site's base url from its location by using one of the methods here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420881/javascript-jquery-method-to-find-base-url-from-a-string -- then just combine that with my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Got it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript):

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
};
```

Then, the check becomes easy:

```
function load(url) {
    if(window.location.href.endsWith(url)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        window.location.href = url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
function load(url) {
    if(window.location.href === url || window.location.href === 'http://www.example.org/' + url) {
        return false;
    } else {
        window.location.href = url;
    }
}
```

But it's hard to know without knowing more about how the `load` function might be used.