# how to get the base url in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

I am building a website with [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter), I have various resources that I load with the [base_url](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) helper function like this

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.base_url('assets/css/themes/default.css').'" id="style_color"/>`

which produces (i.e. www.mysite.com)

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.mysite.com/assets/css/themes/default.css" id="style_color"/>`

I can then swap this resource with another in javascript like this

`$('#style_color').attr("href", "assets/css/themes/" + color_ + ".css");`

what happens is that it will try to load the resource without using the absolute path generated by php, so my solution was adding a dummy tag in every page with php like this

`<div id="base_url" class="'.base_url().'"></div>`

I then modified the javascript line to

`$('#style_color').attr("href", $('#base_url').attr("class") + "assets/css/themes/" + color_ + ".css");`

it does work but it doesn't look elegant at all, so, I would appreciate any help on how to maybe generate this base url from within javascript or any other solution, thanks :)

---

I preferred a Javascript only solution and since I am using [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter), a `document.base_url` variable with the segments of the url from the `protocol` to the `index.php` seemed handy

`document.base_url = base_url('index.php');`

with the function `base_url()` being

```
function base_url(segment){
   // get the segments
   pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
   // find where the segment is located
   indexOfSegment = pathArray.indexOf(segment);
   // make base_url be the origin plus the path to the segment
   return window.location.origin + pathArray.slice(0,indexOfSegment).join('/') + '/';
}
```

Comment: I am using the same thing but I am using hidden readonly field to store base_url() as I was facing some problem passing it in class name.

Comment: I dont get why you add a class with a `base_url`, you can read this to see how to get the base_url in js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420881/javascript-jquery-method-to-find-base-url-from-a-string/11775016#11775016

Answer (score 226, accepted):

## Base URL in JavaScript

You can access the current url quite easily in JavaScript with `window.location`

You have access to the segments of that URL via this `locations` object.  For example:

```
// This article:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246818/how-to-get-the-base-url-in-javascript

var base_url = window.location.origin;
// "http://stackoverflow.com"

var host = window.location.host;
// stackoverflow.com

var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
// ["", "questions", "21246818", "how-to-get-the-base-url-in-javascript"]
```

In Chrome Dev Tools, you can simply enter `window.location` in your console and it will return all of the available properties.

---

Further reading is available on [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420881/javascript-jquery-method-to-find-base-url-from-a-string)

Comment: I am not convinced about this answer being right. base_url is defined in php (server side), how do you get in JS/client side?

Comment: @PC. `base_url` (in this example) is just the name of my variable. it could be `baseURL`, `urlBase`, or anything.

Answer (score 9):

One way is to use a script tag to import the variables you want to your views:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.base_url = <?php echo json_encode(base_url()); ?>;
</script>
```

Here, I wrapped the base_url with json_encode so that it'll automatically escape any characters to valid Javascript. I put base_url to the global Window so you can use it anywhere just by calling base_url, but make sure to put the script tag above any Javascript that calls it. With your given example:

```
...
$('#style_color').attr("href", base_url + "assets/css/themes/" + color_ + ".css");
```

Answer (score 6):

**Base URL in JavaScript**

Here is simple function for your project to get base URL in JavaScript.

```
// base url
function base_url() {
    var pathparts = location.pathname.split('/');
    if (location.host == 'localhost') {
        var url = location.origin+'/'+pathparts[1].trim('/')+'/'; // http://localhost/myproject/
    }else{
        var url = location.origin; // http://stackoverflow.com
    }
    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is done simply by doing this variable.

```
var base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>'
```

This will have base url now. And now make a javascript 
function that will use this variable

```
function base_url(string){
    return base_url + string;
}
```

And now this will always use the correct path.

```
var path    =   "assets/css/themes/" + color_ + ".css"
$('#style_color').attr("href", base_url(path) );
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var baseTags = document.getElementsByTagName("base");
var basePath = baseTags.length ? 
    baseTags[ 0 ].href.substr( location.origin.length, 999 ) : 
    "";
```

Answer (score 4):

To get exactly the same thing as `base_url` of `codeigniter`, you can do:

```
var base_url = window.location.origin + '/' + window.location.pathname.split ('/') [1] + '/';
```

this will be more useful if you work on pure Javascript file.

Answer (score 3):

You can make PHP and JavaScript work together by generating the following line in each page template:

```
<script>
document.mybaseurl='<?php echo base_url('assets/css/themes/default.css');?>';
</script>
```

Then you can refer to document.mybaseurl anywhere in your JavaScript. This saves you some debugging and complexity because this variable is always consistent with the PHP calculation.

Comment: What about browser compatibility with this? Is it possible that some browsers (or older ones) this could fail?

Comment: this should be cross browser because the differences are eliminated by a server-side script. this code may not be "portable", meaning that you might have to adjust the path prefix when you move the server.

Answer (score 1):

Should you want what is exactly specified in the web page, just use:

```
document.querySelector('head base')['href']
```

Answer (score 0):

in **resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php** file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var baseUrl = '<?=url('');?>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have your global scripts file and you don't want to define that URL repeatedly in other files. That's the point where BASE_URL kicks in.

In your global_script.js file, do this

```
<script>
 var BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8000";
</script>
```

Then you can use that variable anywhere else to call your URL. For example...

```
<script>
   fetch(`{{BASE_URL}}/task-create/`,{
         ..............
            
        }).then((response) => {
            .............
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I may be late but for all the Future geeks. Firstly i suppose you want to call base_url in your `.js` file. so lets consider you are calling it on below sample `.js` file

**sample.js**

```
var str = $(this).serialize(); 

jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: base_url + "index.php/sample_controller",
dataType: 'json',
data: str,
success: function(result) {
alert("Success");
}
```

In the above there is no base_url assigned.Therefore the code wont be working properly. But it is for sure that you'll be calling the `.js` in between  `<head></head>` or `<body></body>`of View file by using `<script> </script>` tag.  So to call `base_url` in`.js` file, we have to write the below code where you plan to call the `.js` file. And it is recommended that you create common header file and place the below code and all the calling style sheets (`.css`) and javascript (`.js`) file there. just like below example.

**common header file**

```
<head>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/sample.js">

<script>
  var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';  
</script>


</head>
```

Now the `base_url` will work in `sample.js` file as well. Hope it helped.