# Get URL Parameter using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui

How can I get the third URL segment for the  following URL using JQuery ?

```
192.168.0.108:85/new_caretech/nurse
```

and

```
 192.168.0.108:85/new_caretech/index.php/nurse
```

I want the uri nurse from either of the  above mentioned URL's

Comment: Pls have look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246818/how-to-get-the-base-url-in-javascript

Comment: Try `<?php echo $this->uri->segment(1); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your `base_url` is. Check in `appplication/config/config.php`  on these lines:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

By default, Codeigniter is set so that your base_url is blank but you should set this to your current server, in your case it seems like it should be  `192.168.0.108:85/new_caretech/` and your index_page is defaulted to index.php.. this can be changed in htaccess. But for now, we will say its set to index.php. Therefore to obtain your URI segements you need this:

if your URI is:

```
192.168.0.108:85/new_caretech/index.php/some/another
```

and you want to get the word `another` then you use :

```
$this->uri->segment(2);
```

As you can see, it will look at the segments past your base_url/index_page numbered from left to right.

You can then set this to a variable and pass it to your view for JS or directly to HTML.