# How to get the base url variable on a deployed Heroku node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
console.log(process.env.BASE_URL);   #output: undefined
```

Say my heroku app's host name is: https://RyanCameron-app.herokuapp.com

**How should I go about getting that base_url on heroku?**

I am looking for a solution to avoid to respectively uncomment/comment out the following lines:

```
const url = 'https://RyanCameron-app.herokuapp.com/projects/eovendo' //production 
//const url = 'http://localhost:3000'                                //development
```

It has become quite annoying ..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Backend

This checks if you are in production or development mode and assigns the according url depending on the mode.

```
const production  = 'https://examplePage.com';
const development = 'http://localhost:3000/';
const url = (process.env.NODE_ENV ? production : development);
```

**Explanation:**
`process.env.NODE_ENV` will resolve to `undefined` if you are running on localhost *production mode*. And return `production` if you have deployed the app *production mode*.

**Note**: just because you have deployed the app doesn't necessarily mean you have changed the NODE_ENV

---

### Frontend

Make use of the javascript window to extract the url

```
const url = window.location.origin;
```

---

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Base URL in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21246938/10303343)

```
// This article: // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246818/how-to-get-the-base-url-in-javascript

var base_url = window.location.origin; // "http://stackoverflow.com"

var host = window.location.host; // stackoverflow.com

var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' ); // ["", "questions", "21246818", "how-to-get-the-base-url-in-javascript"]
```

Comment: "ReferenceError: window is not defined". Unfortunately the solution does not work backend - I know I didn't specify whether it should work back- or frontend but I was actually looking for a backend way. Anyway upvoted for an answer that works for frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Set a config variable, HEROKU_APP_NAME or HOST - something obvious. You can access that in the backend but then you can also write it out into the DOM and have your front end access it from there.

Comment: The config variable sounds like I would have to uncomment/comment whenever I deploy the app. And to write it out in the frontend just to send it to the backend sounds like a pain - basically Marat Badykov's solution.