# I want to show image in img tag when ajax is call in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to show an image in `img` tag. when ajax is called in CodeIgniter.
this is the code which receives the data from the database and displays it in a bootstrap model. but the main problem is that I want to show an image in `img` tag but it not showing.

```
        $(".Edit-modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function (e) {
        var button = $(e.relatedTarget); 
        var ID = button.parents("tr").attr("data-id");
        var modal = $(this);
        $.ajax({
        url: "'.base_url().'Employees/master_get_employees",
        data: {ID:ID},
        type: "POST",
        success:function(output){
        try{
        var outputData = JSON.parse(output);
modal.find("#EditImage").attr("'.base_url().'src",outputData.pic);
        }
        catch(ex){
        var split = output.split("::");
        if(split[0] === "FAIL"){
        Shafiq.notification(split[1],split[2])
        }else{
        Shafiq.notification("Could Not Load Data, Please Contact System Administrator For Further Assistance","error");
        }
        }
        }
        });
        });
```

And This is the `Img` tag where I want to display image.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="EditcontactNoSelector">Employee Picture</label>
<img src="" id="EditImage" alt="Not Found">
</div>
</div>
```

And this is the function through which data is fetched from the database

```
public function master_get_employees()
    {
        if ($this->input->post()) { //If Any Values Posted
            if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) { //If Request Generated From Ajax
                $ID = $this->input->post('ID');
                if (!isset($ID) || !is_numeric($ID)) {
                    echo "FAIL::Something went wrong with POST request, Please contact system administrator for further assistance::error";
                    return;
                }
                $table = "employees e";
                $selectData = "e.id AS ID,e.Phone,e.Mobile,e.CNIC,e.Perm_Address,e.Picture as pic,d.name as Designation,s.title as Shift, e.Name,e.Father_Name  AS FatherName,e.Phone AS Contact,e.JoinDate,e.BasicSalary, e.Pres_Address AS Address,e.IsEnabled";
                $where = array(
                    'e.id' => $ID, 'e.IsActive' => 1
                );
                $result = $this->Common_model->select_fields_where_like_join($table, $selectData,$where, TRUE);
                print json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are aware that `base_url()` is a server side function right? did you create a js implementation? further "it is not displaying" isn't helpful. what is your json response? what is happening? any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have `base_url()` function in javascript to find base url of you site.
If so then you can use

`$("#EditImage").attr("src",base_url()+outputData.pic);`

If you don't have `base_url()` function in javascript you can find it here:
[how to get the base url in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246818/how-to-get-the-base-url-in-javascript/21246938)

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
url: "'.base_url().'Employees/master_get_employees",
```

You can use below,

```
url: "<?php echo site_url('Employees/master_get_employees'); ?>",
```

Also at server side if you need only image url then just create image url from $result, store it in variable like $img_path in "master_get_employees" function and then just

```
echo json_encode(['img_path'=>$img_path]);
```

And in ajax success just do below

```
$("#EditImage").attr('src',outputData.img_path);
```