# How o get site URL on server using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the site base url using javascript . I am using

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var baseURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + pathArray[1]+'/';
```

This is working for `mysite.com/project1` but not for `mysite.com`.

How can I check this for both the urls ? I have to send ajax request to the url.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please remove the PHP tag, this question has fundamentally nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/get-current-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base URL should be defined in a special tag in header:

```
<head>
<base href="http://example.com/project1/">
</head>
```

Then you can read it with Javascript:
in modern browsers

```
var baseURL = document.baseURI
```

or in older

```
var baseURL = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should work (depending on your definition of "base URL"):

```html
<script>
 /**
 * Get the parts of an URL.
 *
 * @param url URL to fetch information from
 * @return parts of an URL
 */
function getURLParts(url) {
    var parser = document.createElement('a');
    parser.href = url;
    return parser;
}

// Show the URL information
var parser = getBaseURL(window.location);
alert(parser.protocol);
alert(parser.host);
alert(parser.hostname);
alert(parser.port);
alert(parser.pathname);
alert(parser.hash);
alert(parser.search);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use the location property of window e.g. `window.location.href`

```html
<script>
  alert(window.location.href);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need the base URL of the current Website. From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420881/javascript-jquery-method-to-find-base-url-from-a-string):

```
pathArray = window.location.href.split( '/' );
protocol = pathArray[0];
host = pathArray[2];
url = protocol + '//' + host;
```