# How can I get the URL of an app running in Tomcat, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, tomcat

I am not sure if my heading makes sense. This code example will make things clear, perhaps. I am hosting a simple Web service using Tomcat. I also have some HTML/JavaScript making calls to the web service. I use the XMLHttp for the same. This is an example:

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET','http://mywebservice.com/rest/main',false);  
//xmlhttp.open('GET','http://localhost:8080/appName/rest/main',false);  
xmlhttp.send();
getNames(xmlhttp);
```

Each time I deploy this web service on a certain Tomcat instance (local or cloud),  the URL in the xmlhttp.open() call needs to be manually modified. See the commented code.

Is it possible to fetch this base URL programmatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plese refer [How to extract base URL from a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420881/how-to-extract-base-url-from-a-string-in-javascript)

```js
pathArray = location.href.split('/');
protocol = pathArray[0];
host = pathArray[2];
url = protocol + '//' + host;
```

hope it will help